# php, jquery, flash & .click function in Firefox 3 - stumper

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, flash, flashvars

I have a page that is using PHP to build itself and then uses Jquery to embed some SWF's into the page with different Flashvars based off the DB connection in the PHP section of code. I then have a jQuery .click(function(){ that fires a simple alert at the moment to test for functionality - this works as expected in Safari, but for some strange reason the .click will not fire under Firefox ? Code is below, can someone shed some light on the Firefox issue:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

```
$('#gallery<? echo $count; ?>').flash({
    // test_flashvars.swf is the flash document
    swf: 'button.swf',
    width: 570,
    height: 80,
    // these arguments will be passed into the flash document
    params: {
        wmode: 'transparent',

        },

        flashvars: {
        myText: "<?php echo urlencode($row['gal_Title']); ?>"       
    }
});
$('#gallery<? echo $count; ?>').click(function(){
alert('Alert <?php echo $count; ?>');
});


<? 
    $count = $count+1;
} else {
}
}
mysql_free_result($GalleryItems);
?>
```

The page ostensibly works and I suppose I could move the .click function through to the swf as a clickVar but I wanted the click to initiate an AJAX call to update a section of the page which would then cause me issues with grabbing the call from flash back into the jQuery elements - no ?

Many thanks for any help,

MM

Answer (score 1):

I believe Flash eats the onclick in some browsers - having never had to do this myself, I'm not certain. Is it possible for you to capture the click within Flash and make a call with **ExternalInterface** back out to JavaScript?